Are there aperiodic tilesets with 7-fold rotational symmetry?
In my explorations, I have seen non-periodic tilings with 7-fold rotational symmetry, and I've seen substitutions for such tilings, however I haven't seen anywhere a tileset which enforces such a tiling using local matching rules (i.e. edge markings or bumps and nicks in the tiles). Is there such a thing in the 7-fold case?

The paper "Matching rules and substitution tilings" shows that for any reasonable substitution tiling there exists some local rules which force the substitution. So pick any substitution and the corresponding matching rules.
